# How to include logic app dev and uat parameters JSON file in Build Definition articrafts

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I have parameters json file `ReadData.uat.parameters.json` in my logic app. `Logic app Build Definitions` has below configurations.

In `WorkFlows.sln`, I have multiple logic apps.

[image]

Here `WorkFlows` folder has multiple logic apps.

[image: gic a]

Below are the contents of specific Logic app .

[image]

Unfortunately, in `Articrafts`, `ReadData.uat.parameters.json` file missing but `ReadData.json` and `ReadData.parameters.json` files got added to `Articrafts` folder.

How to include `ReadData.uat.parameters.json` file aswell in `Build Articrafts`?

Comment: You can check if the `ReadData.uat.parameters.json` file is added to the `.gitignore` file of the repo.  If not, you can try to run with the private agent, and then check if the `ReadData.uat.parameters.json` file is copied to the `a`folder under the local `\ agent \ _work \ a` path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to include logic app dev and uat parameters JSON file in Build Definition articrafts

You should set the **Build Action** to **content** for the `ReadData.uat.parameters.json` file:

[image]

In this case, the `ReadData.uat.parameters.json` will be copy to the `bin` folder when you build the project. So, the copy task can copy it from the `bin` folder to artifact.

Hope this helps.